# c# Null value returning from Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Currently have a list that you are able to add customer details to through user input. later in the software I then use linq to search the list in order to find if the customer details already exist in the list. I currently have an if statement (listed below) that takes the return value from linq and displays if the customer has details already stored on the list.

```
    Customer cust = finder.list.where(c => c.ID.ToString() == textBox.txt).FirstOrDefault();

    if(cust.ID == null)
    {
        lstDisplay.items.add("Customer details not stored")
    }
```

The issue I am having is that the program crashes once it reaches the if statement with the error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

train was null.

how to I handle null being returned.

If null is returned to the value train.ID I want to compare it to null like I have in the if statement. If it is null then I want to be able to display the message box Like I have done

Comment: Your trying to see if cust.ID is null, you need to check if the entire CUST object is null

Comment: Simple solution: check if `cust` is null

Comment: Is linq aware that the ID field in the customer table is nullable? i.e. "int?" (question mark intended)

Comment: That's not valid Linq...`Where` is capitalized.

Comment: Also in your `Where` condition, if `ID == null`, then this will fail before you ever get to the `if` statement: `c.ID.ToString()`. So you should change that part as well: `.Where(c => c.ID?.ToString() == textBox.txt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `cust` is null

```
if(cust?.ID == null)
{
    lstDisplay.items.Add("Customer details not stored")
}
```

Comment: Checking for `null` on `cust` should be enough:  `if(cust == null)`.

Comment: @JuanR Should be, you'd think ID was a required field :)

Comment: @JuanR yeah, in the OP's original code, if `ID == null`, then the `c.ID.ToString()` call in the `Where` condition will fail before the `if` statement is ever reached...

Comment: Also, `Add` should be capitalized...